# Does a bounded martingale imply a bounded stochastic integral?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a uniformly bounded continuous martingale with $X_0=0$. I am trying to show that $$Y_t:=\int_0^t|X_s|^p\text{sgn}(X_s)dX_s$$ is a true martingale, where $p\geq1$. As $Y$ is a local martingale, the necessary and sufficient condition for this is that, for all $t\geq0$, the family $$\mathcal{Y}_t=\{Y_T:T\text{ is a stopping time with }T\leq t\}$$ is uniformly integrable. I imagine that the way to show this is that (I suspect), $(Y_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ is uniformly bounded for any non-random $T\geq0$. However, I do not know how to show this - even if $X$ is uniformly bounded, could it not be "moving around" fast enough that the integral is not necessarily bounded? I feel that my understanding of when stochastic integrals are true martingales is lacking, so any advice would be very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that $Y_t$ is bounded, but I think you can show it's a true martingale by using the BDG inequalities.

Recall one condition that ensures $Y$ is a martingale is $\mathbb{E}[\langle Y,Y \rangle_t] < \infty$ for all $t$.  Let $K$ be such that $|X_s| \le K$ for all $s$.  Then we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\langle Y,Y \rangle_t] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t |X_s|^{2p}d\langle X,X \rangle_s\right] \\
&\le K^{2p} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t d\langle X,X \rangle_s\right] \\
&= K^{2p}\mathbb{E}[\langle X,X \rangle_t].
\end{align*}

Now, by the BDG inequality, we know $\mathbb{E}[\langle X,X \rangle_t] \le c\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{s \le t}|X_s|^2\right] \le c K^2 < \infty$ for some universal $c > 0$.
Hence we conclude
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\langle Y,Y \rangle_t] &\le K^{2p}\mathbb{E}[\langle X,X \rangle_t] < \infty.
\end{align*}
and therefore $Y$ is a true martingale.

Comment: Thanks very much for that response - I think you're correct, and it seems that the condition you listed ($\mathbb{E}([Y]_t)<\infty$) for all $t$ is an important one to remember. Am I correct in thinking that if the boundedness condition on $X$ was not there, we would have no way of saying that this was a true martingale? On another point - am I correct in thinking that this particular local martingale $Y$ is non-negative and thus a supermartingale?

Comment: @verygoodbloke If we didn't have the boundedness condition on $X$, this proof wouldn't work, but there could be other ways of showing $Y$ is a true martingale.  For example, if $X$ were a Brownian motion, we could compute $\mathbb{E}[\langle Y,Y\rangle_t]$ directly.  To your other point, I don't think this $Y$ is non-negative in general.  In fact, since $Y$ is a continuous local martingale with $Y_0=0$, the only way for $Y$ to be non-negative is if it is identically $0$.